# Delay issue in analytics reporting api v4 - Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am facing delay issue while fetching data from google analytics using analytics reporting api. sometimes it prints incomplete data(when I tried to fetch data from past  10-20 minutes.) Does anyone have idea how much  delay does this api takes to reflect data from view and how to resolve the issue of incomplete data ?

Answer (score 1):

Processing latency is 24-48 hours, if you want to obtain stable data you have to refer to those of the previous 48h.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en